# Different seed for development and production

Tags: entity-framework

What is the recommended approach to seed a database differently using Entity Framework (6+) depending on the build configuration (Debug / Release)?

Right now I am using the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer. During development I like to have fake data in my database for testing. So I create this test data in the Seed method of the Configuration class (that came with enabling code-first). However, each time I publish the product via build server I have to comment a lot of code inside my seed method, commit this, create the release, and then undo all the comments to continue development with the test data.

I guess this is not the way to go. So I hope you can tell me the proper way to do it.

Comment: Can't you use the `#if DEBUG` preprocessor directive? Or else introduce your own build configuration.

Comment: I was thinking of that. However, I am not sure if that is the way to go. If there is something I have never seen before I often start to think that I might be wrong.

Comment: That's how I would do it, for sure!

Comment: I had an xml file for this - read the data from xml and then do the seed. Use different seed xml for different environments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there are many possibilities

1. Preprocessor directive

One is like you and Gert Arnold already talked about, using the `#if DEBUG`:

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
#if DEBUG
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Test User" },
    );
#else
    context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
        new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Productive User" },
    );
#endif
}
```

2. Configuration

Another way would be with configuration in the appsettings.json, maybe you want to set up the application with development-data, you can add something like

```
{ "environment" : "development" }
```

and in the seed you check for this:

```
protected override void Seed(BookService.Models.BookServiceContext context)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    builder.AddInMemoryCollection();
    var config = builder.Build();

    if (config["environment"].Equals("development"))
    {
        context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Test User" },
        );
    }
    else if (config["environment"].Equals("producion"))
    {
        context.Authors.AddOrUpdate(x => x.Id,
            new Author() { Id = 1, Name = "Productive User" },
        );
    }
}
```

3. Environment variables (solution for **asp net core**)

(see also https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/environments.html)

You can add an environment variable

[image]
and later on via DI:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        SeedDataForDevelopment();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: I had posted an answer here earlier, which actually didn't work, I've deleted it. For users of DbContext HasData, it won't work to conditionally include the 'HasData' statements. Once the migration scripts are generated (with the data included) it will seed production, regardless of what the ModelBuilder does.