# EF Core 2.1 seeding guidance

Tags: seeding, ef-core-2.1

Please provide some guidance for the following problem:

- I have two data configurations to support, each including different initial data. Imagine two types of customers, pet supply stores and book stores. We might have a list of products for each with which we want to initially seed the database when installing on a new machine (no need for dog food items for bookstore customers or mystery novel items for pet store customers). The table structure works for either just fine; only the seed data is different.

Because of how EF Core 2.1 manages seed data, migrating it across new versions, etc., is it practical to seed one or the other or both datasets somehow? Or is this beyond the scope for HasData(), which seems well-suited for a single "configuration" but not well-adapted for two different sets of seed data depending on which product is being built/installed? If it is reasonable to do this, what about unit testing? Seems that I need to run some tests for one configuration and some for another; yes?

I have looked at this item:
[Different seed for development and production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39131577/different-seed-for-development-and-production)
but am not sure this is a reasonable way to handle my situation. I appreciate your thoughts about how you'd approach this problem given EF Core 2.1/ASP NET Core/xUnit.

Comment: "two data configurations to support".  
Does that mean you've got two DbContext instances, or you've got all of those tables defined in one DbContext?